# Netbeans: Jforum text box not editable

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans, textbox, client-side

[image]I'm making a chat program between a server and client. The client text box is not allowing me to enter anything. The textbook is set to editable and enabled.

Comment: Please provide more context. What have you tried already, how does your code look like?

Comment: I added more context. The code that interact with the textfield is simple. try {
            String mout = Ctxt_area.getText().trim();
            out.writeUTF(mout);
        } catch (Exception E) {

        }
               }      however the  textfield is set to enable and editable but once it is running it wont allow me to add anything